# Programming language suggestion - Dynamic and multidimensional array - cplex or gurobi

Tags: programming-languages, dynamic-arrays, cplex, gurobi

Currently I have been using MATLAB to solve the problems that I have been dealing with. In my MATLAB code, I call CPlex or GUROBI solvers to solve large Linear Programming problems. In each call of my MATLAB code, CPlex or GUROBI  is called more than 10^5 times. This causes a high computational load and it takes too much to solve larger problems. However, I want to switch to another programming language which is,

- capable of calling one of these (CPlex or GUROBI ),
- capable of calling one of these solvers (CPlex or GUROBI ) too many times (let's say 10^6 times) and in each call without significant reduction in performance and without any significant increase in run time.
- capable of using dynamic arrays (namely, when I run my code, It will get some user parameters and it will define matrices of different sizes in each run.)
- capable of defining multi-dimensional arrays, not array of arrays.

At this point I have found three options

1. Fortran: It seems quite OK but I have some concerns whether can it efficiently be able to call solvers too many times. It seems that I can only use Fortran with Cplex. I googled Fortran+GUROBI but results were not encouraging.
2. Visual Basic.NET : It seems that calling both Cplex and GUROBI is possible with Visual Basic but I am not sure about the performance.
3. Python: Both integrable with CPlex and GUROBI .

In conclusion, I request your suggestions to go forward. My preference is to start with a programming language in which it is possible to use both GUROBI and CPlex.

Comment: I can read from the web site of Gurobi that it support C. With the interoperability between C and fortran, you are all set up!

Comment: I agree but I wonder whether this interoperations between C and Fortran cause any performance reduction? Or are these interoperations are required in compilation? I write some programs but have to tell you that I am not an expert in computer Programming. And what do you think about Python?

Comment: Both C and fortran allow you to get the best performance when your code is well designed. As far as I can tell, there should be no performance issue. From my own experience, I have had no issue up to now. I usually write in C what is easy to write in C and in fortran what is easy to write in fortran and let the compilers and linker do the rest of the job. So far so good.

Comment: C is likely to be the most efficient choice, but it is also easy to make a mistake. It was described to me as "assembler with extra knobs", and that description really does fit. If you don't know programming, there are huge numbers of tutorials out there on the internet on programming in C. Also what you learn in C is likely to be more easily transferable to other languages like C++, C#, Java. In comparison, Fortran feels like a dead end. I used Fortran for 10+ years, but haven't touched it for the last 20 years.

Comment: Other choices might be C++ which is very nearly as efficient as C, but adds lots of object-oriented stuff on top which helps with code structure etc. Both C and C++ require you to take care with memory management, i.e. allocating and releasing memory, but that extra level of control can gain you in efficiency too. Other valid choices would be C# and Python. C# is actually rather good, efficient and does automatic memory management. Visual Studio is good. I have not used Python yet, but would expect lower efficiency. I would *NEVER* use Visual Basic - I have never made it work well.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick, My no.1 concern about C,C++ or C# is the dynamic array sizing. During the run of my algorithm, some new arrays will be needed to be defined. The sizes of these new arrays will be determined by some parameters which will be calculated during the run. That makes pre-allocating of memory for such arrays impossible or at least harder. Doesn't it? From other aspects C and all of its derivatives seems to be OK. What would you say about that? All of your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Creating an array of size determined at run time is absolutely normal in C and C++. See for example http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/ EVERY other language must internally be doing something similar. All they do is layer on some syntactic sugar to make it look simpler. Using C or C++ allows full control over when you allocate and delete such memory and how you use it, which is where you can gain efficiency. Effectively the overhead is on you when you write the code (once) so the machine can go as fast as possible with minimal overheads (10^6 times).

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick, I do not have the same experience as you do, but I definitely do not agree with when you say fortran is a dead end. When I learnded fortran 15 years ago as undergrad, people said the exact same thing. Today, it is a big part of what I get my paycheck from. I am a research scientist, and from what I see in the physics-related research , fortran still has a bright future. They use C++ too but mainly for wrapping, the core remains in fortran. I would like to point out that I am not a fortran-centric. I use C/C++, java, python too, to list a few.

Comment: OK, I admit that I overstated Fortran's demise. I used it a lot and am still very fond of it. There is a huge amount of very good code already in Fortran, and for many in physics research and similar fields it is the obvious choice (I know, I have a PhD in computational physics). But if I was writing a commercial or business system, it would not be my first choice. If I was new to programming and starting out, again I would look to another language. One of the C-like languages (C#, Java, C++ etc) is more likely to get you reusable skills and be understood by more people.

Comment: Slightly off topic rant - please, anyone who is interested in really understanding programming really should look at a variety of languages, particularly those like Fortran. The language is over 50 years old and still powerful and useful. Many modern languages may well be dead and buried long before they get that old. Clearly Fortran does some thing(s) right. Same goes for Lisp. Anyone who only knows one language probably doesn't really know how to program. @innoSPG - thanks for standing up for Fortran. It's not a dead end, it's just somewhat niche in its uses at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is using Python with 
Pyomo.

[Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/about/) (www.pyomo.org) "... is a Python-based open-source software package that supports a diverse set of optimization capabilities for formulating and analyzing optimization models." As such, you can use Python constructs to help build a model. After building the model, you can then run it on gurobi, cplex and many more. And since the solver is just an argument in the solve function, running it in both is just a one word difference. Below is a simple example.

```
# model.py
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()

model.x = Var([1,2], domain=NonNegativeReals)

model.OBJ = Objective(expr = 2 * model.x[1] + 3 * model.x[2])

model.Constraint1 = Constraint(expr=3 * model.x[1] + 4 * model.x[2] >= 1)
```

From the command line you could then solve

```
pyomo solve model.py --solver=gurobi
```

or

```
pyomo solve model.py --solver=cplex
```

You could solve it using a script as well. This sky is the limit and the [support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pyomo-forum) is great.

Comment: Have you ever tried Pyomo with commercial/academic solvers (especially CPlex or Gurobi)? If you did, I would really like to read your experiences with it. In CPlex or GUROBI documentation I have never read about Pyomo. It sounds interesting to me. I will search for Pyomo. Thank you.

Comment: I use it all the time with Gurobi, and I have used it a few times with CPlex (Gurobi works better for my types of problems). I really love it.

Comment: That's amazing. I'll try python and pyomo. I have one more question. Why would you prefer Python over C and C derivative programming languages? I ask that because some C users have concerns about the performance of the Python. Thank you.

Comment: Python definitely would have some advantages in terms of ease of use for exploratory programming. It is a proper modern language with lots of neat and clever features, and I need to find time to learn it properly. Definitely also sure that a properly programmed solution in C or C++ would be faster than a Python equivalent, especially called one million times. But, it is a conscious trade-off. What you need to do may be easier to program in Python and that counts for a lot. You might even write it in Python to get your head round how to solve it, then re-write in C++ to speed it up.

Comment: I found in my case, my python codes runs for < 5 seconds and Gurobi runs for > 5 minutes. Sure, I could write it in C and it would run in < 1 seconds, but that is not a lot of savings on the large scale. However, Python code will be at least half as many lines and way easier to write and debug than C.